# Wicket IPackageResourceGuard Image in Listview

Tags: listview, resources, wicket

I am unable to add an image to my listview located in my /webapp/images/ directory.

```
ListView<Games> gamesList = new ListView<Games>("gamesList", games) {

        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        @Override
        protected void populateItem(ListItem<Games> item) {
            Games game = item.getModel().getObject();
            item.add(new Image("champImage", "hello").add(new AttributeModifier("src", "dorans.png")));
            item.add(new Image("enemyChampImage", "world").add(new AttributeModifier("src", "dorans.png")));
            item.add(new Label("champName", game.getChampName()));
            item.add(new Label("enemyChampName", game.getEnemyChampName()));
            item.add(new Label("goldSpent", game.getGoldSpent()));
            item.add(new Image("item0", "name1").add(new AttributeModifier("src", "dorans.png")));
            item.add(new Image("item1", "name2").add(new AttributeModifier("src", "dorans.png")));
            item.add(new Image("item2", "name3").add(new AttributeModifier("src", "dorans.png")));
            item.add(new Image("item3", "name4").add(new AttributeModifier("src", "dorans.png")));
            item.add(new Image("item4", "name5").add(new AttributeModifier("src", "dorans.png")));
            item.add(new Image("item5", "name6").add(new AttributeModifier("src", "dorans.png")));
            item.add(new Image("item6", "name7").add(new AttributeModifier("src", "dorans.png")));
        }
    };
```

I read online that Wicket (version#) added an IPackageResourceGuard so unwanted files are not accessed, so I added this to my WicketApplication.java.

```
@Override
public void init()
{
    super.init();

    // add your configuration here
    IPackageResourceGuard packageResourceGuard = this.getResourceSettings().getPackageResourceGuard();
    if (packageResourceGuard instanceof SecurePackageResourceGuard) {
        SecurePackageResourceGuard guard = (SecurePackageResourceGuard) packageResourceGuard;
        guard.addPattern("+*.png");
    }

}
```

This is to allow .pngs to be used, but I'm still getting the exception!

```
Caused by: org.apache.wicket.request.resource.PackageResource$PackageResourceBlockedException: Access denied to (static) package resource com/riot/itemsets/hello. See IPackageResourceGuard
at org.apache.wicket.request.resource.PackageResource.internalGetResourceStream(PackageResource.java:490) ~[wicket-core-7.0.0.jar:7.0.0]
at org.apache.wicket.request.resource.PackageResource.getResourceStream(PackageResource.java:440) ~[wicket-core-7.0.0.jar:7.0.0]
at org.apache.wicket.request.resource.PackageResource.getCacheKey(PackageResource.java:258) ~[wicket-core-7.0.0.jar:7.0.0]
at org.apache.wicket.request.resource.caching.version.RequestCycleCachedResourceVersion.getVersion(RequestCycleCachedResourceVersion.java:82) ~[wicket-core-7.0.0.jar:7.0.0]
at org.apache.wicket.request.resource.caching.FilenameWithVersionResourceCachingStrategy.decorateUrl(FilenameWithVersionResourceCachingStrategy.java:105) ~[wicket-core-7.0.0.jar:7.0.0]
at org.apache.wicket.core.request.mapper.BasicResourceReferenceMapper.mapHandler(BasicResourceReferenceMapper.java:240) ~[wicket-core-7.0.0.jar:7.0.0]
at org.apache.wicket.request.mapper.ParentPathReferenceRewriter.mapHandler(ParentPathReferenceRewriter.java:91) ~[wicket-request-7.0.0.jar:7.0.0]
at org.apache.wicket.request.mapper.CompoundRequestMapper.mapHandler(CompoundRequestMapper.java:213) ~[wicket-request-7.0.0.jar:7.0.0]
at org.apache.wicket.request.cycle.RequestCycle.mapUrlFor(RequestCycle.java:434) ~[wicket-core-7.0.0.jar:7.0.0]
at org.apache.wicket.request.cycle.RequestCycle.urlFor(RequestCycle.java:534) ~[wicket-core-7.0.0.jar:7.0.0]
... 108 more
```

Comment: Seems that the Image constructor is wrong. Look in examples for images.

Answer (score 0):

In your parent you have :   `<wicket:child></wicket:child>`

In your child : `<wicket:extend></wicket:extend>`

,, need change in your child and you must put this :
`<wicket:extend xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en"
    xmlns:wicket="http://wicket.apache.org/dtds.data/wicket-xhtml1.4-strict.dtd">`

Try it.